# 24 hour countdown script that hits 00:00 every day at 11:00

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timer, countdown

I need a 24 hour countdown on my website that resets every day at 11:00 and after that starts 24 hour cycle again.

I don't need this script to control anything, I just need it to be there for visitors to see, so when they visit for example at 10:00 the will see 1 hour left on the clock and live counting down in format: Hours, Minutes, Seconds
And I need it to ignore clients time zone.

I found similar answer, but there is 1 hour window and it resets after that, I need it to reset immediately, how can I edit it to meet my requirements?

Here's what I found (this count to 21:00 then one hour window and than starts again):

```
var date;
var display = document.getElementById('time');

$(document).ready(function() {
    getTime('GMT', function(time){
        date = new Date(time);
    });    
});

setInterval(function() {
    date = new Date(date.getTime() + 1000);

    var currenthours = date.getHours();
    var hours;
    var minutes;
    var seconds;
    if (currenthours != 21){
        if (currenthours < 21) {
            hours = 20 - currenthours;
        } else {
            hours = 21 + (24 - currenthours);
        }
        minutes = 60 - date.getMinutes();
        seconds = 60 - date.getSeconds();

        if (minutes < 10) {
            minutes = '0' + minutes;
        }
        if (seconds < 10) {
            seconds = '0' + seconds;
        }

        display.innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' +seconds;
    } else { 
        display.innerHTML = 'LIVE NOW';
    }
}, 1000);

function getTime(zone, success) {
    var url = 'http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=' + zone,
        ud = 'json' + (+new Date());
    window[ud]= function(o){
        success && success(new Date(o.datetime));
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild((function(){
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = url + '&callback=' + ud;
        return s;
    })());
}
```

Comment: `currenthours != 21` checks only the hour, regardless if its 21:00 or 21:59, or anything in between.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that 1 hour reset is due to validating hours alone. Try  the following code:

```
var date;
var display = document.getElementById('time');

$(document).ready(function() {
    getTime('GMT', function(time){
        date = new Date(time);
    });    
});

setInterval(function() {
    date = new Date(date.getTime() + 1000);

    var currenthours = date.getHours();
    var currentSecs = date.getSeconds();
    var hours;
    var minutes;
    var seconds;
    if (currenthours == 23 && currentsecs == 0){
        display.innerHTML = 'LIVE NOW';
    } else {
        if (currenthours < 23) {
          hours = 22 - currenthours;
        } else {
          hours = 23;
        }
        minutes = 60 - date.getMinutes();
        seconds = 60 - date.getSeconds();

        if (minutes < 10) {
            minutes = '0' + minutes;
        }
        if (seconds < 10) {
            seconds = '0' + seconds;
        }
     display.innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' +seconds;
    } 
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get accurate day duration even during daylight saving time changes you should stick to date arithmetic.

```
function time() {
    var d1 = new Date();
    var d2 = Date.UTC(d1.getUTCFullYear(),
                      d1.getUTCMonth(),
                      d1.getUTCDate() + (d1.getUTCHours() < 11 ? 0 : 1),
                      11);
    var dh = d2 - d1;
    var hours = Math.floor(dh / 3600000);
    var dm = dh - 3600000 * hours;
    var min = Math.floor(dm / 60000);
    var ds = dm - 60000 * min;
    var sec = Math.floor(ds / 1000);
    var dmilli = ds - 1000 * sec;
    setTimeout(time, dmilli);
    hours = ('0' + hours).slice(-2);
    min = ('0' + min).slice(-2);
    sec = ('0' + sec).slice(-2);
    document.querySelector('#the-final-countdown p').innerHTML = hours + ':' + min + ':' + sec;
}
time();
```